# Getting Error : Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 5] I/O error') when requests.post to API

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get I/O error when hitting API service with Python3.7 and its library `requests==2.22.0` with this code:

```py
request = {
    "SOME_REQUEST_KEY" : "SOME_REQUEST_VALUE"
}
nonce = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "APIKEY": X.APIKEY, "NONCE": str(nonce), "KEY": get_key(json.dumps(request, separators=(',', ':')), str(nonce))}
data = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(request), headers=headers)
if data.status_code == 200:
    result = data.json()
    # print(result)
    responseCode = result['responseCode']
    responseData = result['responseData']
else:
    # print(str(data))
    responseCode = '97'
    responseData = str(data)
```

and getting this error in my logs:

```
General Error [service.py/process_settlement_or_adjint] HTTPConnectionPool(host='my-api-service.svc', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /casa-to-casa-loan (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 5] I/O error'))
```

Strangely, this error has never shown up before. I didn't understand what I miss. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means your api URL was not up or your network is misconfigured so the actual connection to the api server could not be established.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But when i re-run this script without any changes it works properly and this error only happens in my productions server with kubernetes and docker running.